# Adding another column to the SQL Server pivot table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following pivot table query returns only one column. How can I add another column like ***name*** for example?

```html
+------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| definition   | name | January | February | 06-02 | 06-03 | ... | 06-29 | 06-30 | Total |
+------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| dallas       | name1 | 20     |     1 |     1 |     1 | ... |     1 |     1 |    30 |
| newyork      | name2 | 30     |     0 |     1 |     1 | ... |     1 |     1 |    27  |
| newjersey    | name3 | 40     |     0 |     0 |     0 | ... |     1 |     1 |    16 |
+------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

```
   Select 
   isnull (Definition_, 'GrandTotal') AS 'Definition_',
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 1 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS January,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 2 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS Feburary, 
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 3 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS March,    
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 4 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS April,    
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 5 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS May,      
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 6 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS June,  
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 7 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS July,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 8 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS August,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 9 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS September,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 10 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS October,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 11 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS November,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 12 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS December,
   isnull (SUM(OrderQty),0) AS GrandTotal,
    
    FROM Production.WorkOrder
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((DATEPART(YEAR, DueDate), Definition_, ProductID),
    ())order by ProductID;
```

Comment: That query should return more than 1 column, it should return 14; 1 for each month, and another 2 columns called `Definition_` and `GrandTotal`

Comment: Any reason why you didn't use a pivot statement?

Comment: `PIVOT` is pretty restrictive in my opinion, @Tyron78 . For what the OP wants, conditional aggregation seems much better suited. Plus, unlike the `PIVOT` operator, it's transferable to other RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu I guess there won't be a column "GrandTotal" - it's just the NULL-Value within the column "Definition_"

Comment: Yes there will be, @Tyron78 , this last column: `isnull (SUM(OrderQty),0) AS GrandTotal,` Which then creates a syntax error as after the comma (`,`) there is a `FROM`.

Comment: @Larnu you are right - I missed that line... sorry

Comment: What I want to do is to add a definition column on the far left side and another column right next to it. In summary: The two columns on the far right, then the monthly totals will appear.

Comment: I would suggest you supply sample data and expected results along side your attempt @VelvetDreams . That'll help explain your goal(s).

Comment: @larnu I added an example to the first post.

Comment: Seems like you just need to add `Name` to your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`...

Comment: I tried many times but failed. Example first line and last line I did like this:  
 SELECT ISNULL (I.CODE, ISNULL (I.NAME, 'GRAND TOTAL')) AS DEFINITION,
...
 GROUP BY 
 GROUPING SETS
 (
 (DATEPART(YEAR, L.DATE_), I.CODE, I.NAME), 
 ()
 )

Comment: @Meysam Asadi sorry. I tried as you said but failed. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following an example using pivot which should produce the desired result:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  Definition_ VARCHAR(100)
 ,DueDate DATE
 ,OrderQty INT
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
 ('Test1', '2021-01-01', 2)
,('Test1', '2021-01-02', 3)
,('Test1', '2021-01-17', 5)
,('Test1', '2021-02-15', 4)
,('Test1', '2021-02-18', 6)
,('Test1', '2021-10-15', 4)
,('Test1', '2021-12-18', 6);

WITH cteMonth AS(
  SELECT isnull (Definition_, 'GrandTotal') AS 'Definition_'
      ,OrderQty
      ,CASE(DATEPART(MONTH, DueDate))
         WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
         WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
         WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
         WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
       END As Month_
  FROM @t
),
ctePivot AS(
SELECT *
  FROM cteMonth
  PIVOT (SUM(OrderQty) FOR Month_ IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])) as p
)
SELECT [Definition_]
      ,ISNULL([January], 0) + ISNULL([February], 0) + ISNULL([March], 0) + ISNULL([April], 0) + ISNULL([May], 0) + ISNULL([June], 0) +
        ISNULL([July], 0) + ISNULL([August], 0) + ISNULL([September], 0) + ISNULL([October], 0) + ISNULL([November], 0) + ISNULL([December], 0) AS GrandTotal
      ,ISNULL([January], 0) [January]
      ,ISNULL([February], 0) [February]
      ,ISNULL([March], 0) [March]
      ,ISNULL([April], 0) [April]
      ,ISNULL([May], 0) [May]
      ,ISNULL([June], 0) [June]
      ,ISNULL([July], 0) [July]
      ,ISNULL([August], 0) [August]
      ,ISNULL([September], 0) [September]
      ,ISNULL([October], 0) [October]
      ,ISNULL([November], 0) [November]
      ,ISNULL([December], 0) [December]
  FROM ctePivot
```

and with GrandTotal calculated before the pivot:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  Definition_ VARCHAR(100)
 ,DueDate DATE
 ,OrderQty INT
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
 ('Test1', '2021-01-01', 2)
,('Test1', '2021-01-02', 3)
,('Test1', '2021-01-17', 5)
,('Test1', '2021-02-15', 4)
,('Test1', '2021-02-18', 6)
,('Test1', '2021-10-15', 4)
,('Test1', '2021-12-18', 6);

WITH cteMonth AS(
  SELECT isnull (Definition_, 'GrandTotal') AS 'Definition_'
      ,OrderQty
      ,SUM(OrderQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ISNULL(Definition_, 'GrandTotal')) AS GrandTotal
      ,CASE(DATEPART(MONTH, DueDate))
         WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
         WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
         WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
         WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
       END As Month_
  FROM @t
),
ctePivot AS(
SELECT *
  FROM cteMonth
  PIVOT (SUM(OrderQty) FOR Month_ IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])) as p
)
SELECT [Definition_]
      ,GrandTotal
      ,ISNULL([January], 0) [January]
      ,ISNULL([February], 0) [February]
      ,ISNULL([March], 0) [March]
      ,ISNULL([April], 0) [April]
      ,ISNULL([May], 0) [May]
      ,ISNULL([June], 0) [June]
      ,ISNULL([July], 0) [July]
      ,ISNULL([August], 0) [August]
      ,ISNULL([September], 0) [September]
      ,ISNULL([October], 0) [October]
      ,ISNULL([November], 0) [November]
      ,ISNULL([December], 0) [December]
  FROM ctePivot
```

Comment: I added an example to the first post. I want to do like this. Thank you for your answer. Your answer is very long and complex... How can I arrange this in the first T-SQL query?

Comment: If you take my second example, the declare and the insert is only sample data in order to show the example. The long case statement in the firest cteMonth is basically what you do in your query - mapping of the month number to the month name. So the "real magic" happens in ctePivot which is only 4 lines... the last select statement merely serves the purpose  to eliminate NULL values for month where you don't have a qty (see sample data).

Comment: @VelvetDreams furthermore, here if the name is already available in the source data (by the way, providing consumable sample data of the source table would be really helpful) you only have to add it in cteMonth and in the last select statement...

Answer (score 1):

**Looks like you just need to add `NAME` to the grouping:**

> You should use the `GROUPING()` function to check for the total row, instead of `ISNULL`

```
Select 
   Definition_ AS [Definition_],
   CASE WHEN GROUPING(NAME) = 0 THEN NAME ELSE 'GrandTotal' END AS NAME,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 1 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS January,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 2 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS Feburary, 
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 3 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS March,    
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 4 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS April,    
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 5 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS May,      
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 6 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS June,  
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 7 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS July,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 8 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS August,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 9 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS September,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 10 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS October,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 11 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS November,
   isnull (SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,DueDate) WHEN 12 THEN OrderQty END),0) AS December,
   isnull (SUM(OrderQty),0) AS GrandTotal
    
FROM Production.WorkOrder
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
    (DATEPART(YEAR, DueDate), Definition_, NAME, ProductID),
    ()
)
order by ProductID;
```

It's unclear why you are not also selecting `DATEPART(YEAR, DueDate)` and `ProductID`

Comment: I implemented your answer. However, this time I ran into a problem. The column 'GRAND TOTAL' is under 'DEFINITION'. Data values come under month. No problem. Only the text 'GRAND TOTAL' remained on the far left. Under the 'NAME' column, it says 'NULL'. How can I get the text 'GRAND TOTAL' under the 'NAME' column? How can I change the 'NAME' column, column title? Can you review it again?

Comment: You want `NULL` under `Definition` and `Grand Total` under `NAME`? OK have modified

Comment: Dear @Charlieface Thank you so much. My problem is solved. Good luck. PS: I have one more unresolved question on this platform. (stack overflow) Can you review it when you have the chance?